# Can someone explain why my spam flag on this comment was rejected?

Tags: discussion

I flagged [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21145838/getting-error-when-trying-to-overload-indexing-operator#comment31827108_21145838) because it seems to just be advertising some college. Am I misunderstanding the SO definition of SPAM? It doesn't seem to relate to the question at all.

Comment: The SSCCE link is anything but spam.

Comment: The link is wrong, though. Lacks an `s`, has an extra `c`, leads to [Santiago Canyon College](http://www.sccce.org/bsd/joomla/).

Comment: Oh right. It got typoed.

Comment: @CrazyCasta Just because the wrong link was posted doesn't make it spam.  It's just a typoed link.

Comment: Just an honest quick typo @CrazyCasta.

Comment: @CrazyCasta The poster was intending to post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Oh, now that you've posted the correct spelling, I see how that would be useful.

Comment: On spam comments/questions and answers I always [check the user profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1737/roddy). If it is empty (new user) or has only that kind of posts I flag for spam. On higher rep users I'll leave a comment to ask for clarification

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Oops, thought that was the standard SSCCE link (note that we used this link ourselves in the close reasons). Missed the typo in the URL.

I've fixed the URL in the comment. I'm not crazy about the comment itself, but I'll let it stay for now in case it provides some guidance to the asker.

Sorry about that, but at least declined comment flags really don't hurt you in any way.

Comment: Sorry, I just wasn't familiar with the SSCCE acronym (I'm familiar with the general concept of course) and therefore thought it was just utter spam. Thank you for clearing it up.

Comment: If you had realized the typo when you looked the comment flag, would you have still declined the flag?  Does having a SPAM comment still hurt the poster the same as having a SPAM answer deleted (i.e. the -100 rep penalty)?

Comment: Do *any* declined flags hurt you in any way??? :)

Comment: A hand pops up out of my CD tray and slaps me across the face. That doesn't happen for you, @Adam?

Comment: **That's** what that is?!?!  :-O

Comment: @psubsee2003 - I would have edited the comment, which marks the flag as helpful by default. There isn't really a spam flag for comments, just "other" flags that someone can fill out with "spam" as a reason. We've only had a handful of legitimate spammers get to the reputation level required to spam comments in the time I've been here (a few due to that unfortunate period when badges were added to review, but before the audits, but the rest due to sock puppets).

Comment: @BradLarson yeah, I guess I was thinking of one of the auto-nuker comments like "rude or offensive" since "offensive" and "spam" flags on posts effectively are the same.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A **SSCCE** stands for Short Self-Contained Correct Example.

Generally, when you have a coding problem, posting a SSCCE helps us better understand the question.

---

Now you were right to be concerned though.  If I didn't already know what a SSCCE was, I would think it's spam too.  A comment with a link that doesn't actually describe what's at the link is should make you suspicious.

It's best to at least write a complete sentence, so that the reader knows that `sscce.org` isn't just some random and potentially malicious website.

It can be as simple as:

> please post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)

Which at the very least least tells the reader that an SSCCE is a thing that you want them to post.